# DB Structure for storing attributes of places

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have to store data about schools and universities (more entities like language courses are also planned).

List of data I have to store:

- Available learning programs
- Accommodation possibilities
- Availability of special food diets
- etc.

So I created tables for schools and unis:

```
Place (place_id, name, city_id ... )
School (place_id (FK), school_type ...)
University (place_id (FK), ... )
```

And tables for options:

```
Accomodation (accomodation_id, name, description ...)
Activity (activity_id, name, category ...)
...
```

And because it always possible that it will be more than one option I bound them together with tables like this one:

```
Accomodation_to_place (place_id, accomodation_id)
...
```

But I found out that it is really hard to update or even to get data from this whole thing. I have to make 14 Joins and 7 GROUP_CONCAT() in order to get all the information I need.

So I thought there must be some serious flaw in my database design. And I wanted to ask for any ideas how to make it better/easier.

Comment: if you can display the design structure would be better, also if you are not comfortable with 14 joins and .. you can create a view table and the code will simplified a little

Comment: With the setup you've presented thus far, I do not see an obvious flaw in your thinking.  It seems like you legitimately have a ton of different objects and a ton of relationships among them.  However, it strikes me that if you're hoping to bring back a ton of data about a specific place, you're essentially hoping to get documents...on a specific place.  Have you looked at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)?  It is designed from the ground up to have its storage centered around documents.

Comment: @YYY MongoDB looks exactly like what I need, but it is now already too late to use it (project I am working on is not too far from deadline). But thank you for the idea.
Looks like for now I will stick with my 14 joins.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of database normalization is primarily to avoid storing data in a way that is redundant and susceptible to data anomalies.

It sometimes results in complex queries to retrieve all the data, but that's because the nature of the information you're modeling is complex.  A normalized design is nevertheless better for the purpose of avoiding your data becoming a mess.

I would suggest that if you have such complex queries with lots of DISTINCT and GROUP_CONCAT, you may be trying to fetch too much information in a single query.  It isn't necessarily harmful to use two or three queries, and you will probably benefit a lot by making your code easier to read, maintain, and debug.

I wrote about this issue in the chapter titled "Spaghetti Query" in my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/)